# Simple properties of cardinal numbers

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

Sorry for this simple question, but I couldn't find the answer. Can we show without $AC$ that $n\mathfrak{m}=\mathfrak{m}$ for a finite cardinal $n$ and infinite $\mathfrak{m}$. Can you give me a link with the list of similar properties?

Comment: No, we cannot. We cannot even say that $\mathfrak m+1=\mathfrak m$.

Comment: On the one hand, the question itself is a duplicate in the sense that the particular question $n\frak m=m$ was answered before. But a list of "similar properties"? I think this might be borderline too broad. There are a lot of "unusual properties" (in the sense that we don't usually think of them) which are in fact provable in ZF. But how could know that we listed all of them? There's bound to be more. The only thing to do is to try and prove them as you go. The upside is that it's usually fairly straightforward, and if it's not it's usually because you need choice.

Comment: Thanks @Asaf - very interesting