# Is it true without the axiom of choice that every infinite cardinal is larger than every finite cardinal?

Tags: logic, set-theory, cardinals, axiom-of-choice

It seems I'm going to continue a sequence of dumb set-theoretic questions (here's the first one I asked yeserday: [Simple properties of cardinal numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3489764/simple-properties-of-cardinal-numbers?noredirect=1#comment7175933_3489764)). Sorry again if it's a duplicate.

I'm interested if $n\leq\mathfrak{m}$ where $n$ is a finite and $\mathfrak{m}$ is an infinite cardinal, and can it be proved without $AC$? My attempts were the following. Let say we want to prove $2\leq\mathfrak{m}$. Consider a set $M$ with cardinality $\mathfrak{m}$. It follows (?) from the definition of infinite sets that:
\begin{align}
\exists(a\in M)\exists(b\in M):a\neq b
\end{align}
Thus there is a subset of $M$ with cardinality $2$. The natural way to generalize these thoughts is to use the induction. Thus after observing $0$-case we're supposing there is a subset $X$ of $M$ set with cardinality $n$. Then we conclude $X\neq M$, and finally:
\begin{align}
\exists(a\in M):\overline{\overline{\{a\}\cup X}}=n+1
\end{align}
The problem is I'm not sure if this pseudo-proof is valid. This raises the question again...

Comment: What is your definition of $\le$ for cardinal numbers? Your definition of $2$? What is a cardinal number without AC? For such basic set theory question you have to very precise about your definitions. What is the double bar?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I'm trying, but the whole information always overloads my head, so I begin moving on intuitively, but it seems doesn't work.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma  double bar means cardinality which is a separate object the same for all sets connected by a bijection. $\leq$ means the existance of an injective function, $2$ - cardinality of $\{\{\},\{\{\}\}\}$.

Comment: So a sort of equivalence class of idempotent objects. Such a thing need not exist in general.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma But it is fair to mention that such kind of definitions can be justified by [Scott's trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott%27s_trick), including the mentioned definition of cardinals.

Comment: @HanulJeon It's unclear whether the OP knows or uses this technique.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I agree. But I want to mention that this definition can be justified.

Comment: @Henno: In either case, one can always formulate cardinal arithmetic facts as statements about injections/bijections between sets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proof is fine. You're appealing to induction. You would only need to choice if you want to claim that from this proof follows that every infinite set has a countably infinite subset.

There are two key facts here:

1. An infinite set is not empty, since the empty set is finite.
2. Removing finitely many elements from an infinite set still gives us an infinite set, since the union of two finite sets is finite.

That means that if we managed to somehow find a subset of size $n$, then there is a subset of size $n+1$. And by induction that means there are subsets of every finite size.